# Celula Excel com VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Olá,

Estou tentando finalizar uma planilha de excel com VBA, porém não estou conseguindo capturar uma imagem após inserção de dados. Por exemplo: clicar em usuário e ele mostrar a foto da pessoa e também o nome completo. segue abaixo o que ja fiz.

```
    Private Sub TxtUsuario_Change()
       Dim Imagem

       ultimaLinha = Plan16.Cells(Plan16.Cells.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

        For f = 2 To ultimaLinha
        If Cells(f, 1) = TxtUsuario Then
        TxtNome = Cells(f, 4)

        End If
        Next

        End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        linha = 2
        Do Until Plan16.Cells(linha, 1) = ""
        TxtUsuario.AddItem Plan16.Cells(linha, 1)
        linha = linha + 1
        TxtUsuario.SetFocus
        Loop
        Call removeCaption(Me)

        For f = 2 To ultimaLinha
        If Cells(f, 1) = TxtUsuario Then
        TxtNome = Cells(f, 4)

        End If
        Next

        TxtUsuario.SetFocus

        Call removeCaption(Me)
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Ao observar o seu código, percebo que esta faltando declarar o **tipo** da variável local *"Imagem"*. Mesmo não a utilizando, talvez seja bom declarar.

Outra coisa, você esta salvando somente o endereço da imagem na planilha, certo?! Se não, tente fazer dessa forma. Através dos endereço, inicializar a instrução o Excel deve buscar direto da pasta onde a imagem esta alocada.